# Plot many graphs with Blastula in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, blastula

I'm trying to plot different graphs with Blastula, but just the lasted plot is showed.

The code is:

```
library(ggplot2)
summary(iris)
ggplot(iris,aes(x=iris$Species, y=iris$Petal.Length))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
plot(iris)
ggplot(iris,aes(x=iris$Species, y=iris$Petal.Length, fill = iris$Species))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')

email2<-blastula::render_email('MyPath')

email2$send()
```

But the result is only for the last ggplot object, how can I plot multiple graphs ?